# Import task for non-standard key referencing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

The association of two classes as such,

```
class Available < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :structure, class_name: 'Structure', foreign_key: 'product_code'

class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'product_code'
```

has the consequence when importing under a rake task

```
  begin
   Structure.create(
      product_code: row[0],
      destination: row[1],
```

of creating the record with id as the product_code, as well as the product_code attribute itself  `#<Structure id: "CAN752500", product_code: "CAN752500", destination: [...]`

I noted that on a virgin import, with no association defined on the `Structure` model, attribute `id` had its expected value; after specifying `self.primary_key` in the model, the databased values of `id` were over-written with the `product_code` value.

**updated question**
This desired goal is, to maintain `structure.id` as an integer, while having the association on `product_code` functioning.
How can this be defined ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please try to make it clearer.

Comment: I attempted to do so.

Comment: sorry If I don't have the answer to your question, but why use `self.primary_key` instead of just an indexed field ?

Comment: Can you write a code example that does not work as desired and shows the problem?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio That is an option which will be explored.  Trying to remain succint with data that is imported from a third party, I was hoping to maintain the association with the same field data (but that may be a pipe dream).  @chumakoff the offending code is `id: "CAN752500", product_code: "CAN752500"` where I would rather have `id: 1012, product_code: "CAN752500"` .

Comment: Note: while I am still interested in the apporach to solving this problem, I now understand it is wiser to do data handling/manipulation upstream, at the import level, to maintain the rails principles (and some form of sanity!)... and thus avoid this issue altogether.